# Light up key one at a time and

Tags: javascript

I need help with finishing this code.  I need the keys to light one at a time and than turn of the color when the button is pressed.  So if you have the word 'table', the keyletter 't' would start light up untill the button is pressed.  So when the 't' button has been pressed the light turnes off, and the 'a' keyletter ligths up... and so on.

```
//var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
 var q = document.getElementById("q");
 var recogResult;
 var resultAsArray;

var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();

recognition.onresult = function(event) {
    if (event.results.length > 0) {
        recogResult = event.results[0][0].transcript;
        q.innerHTML = recogResult;
    }
    resultAsArray = recogResult.split(''); 
    console.log (resultAsArray);

   var i=0;
   while (i<resultAsArray.length) 
    { // as long as there are more letters in resultAsArray 
    // light 'i' letter 
    changeDivColor(resultAsArray[i]);
```

//the tree lines below is what i need help with

```
    // wait for the 'i' letter(key) to be pressed 
    // when 'i' has been pressed than shut that key light and light the next 'i' letter(key)
    // this should continue until all 'i' have been ligted and pressed.

            i++;
    }
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  console.log(event.which);
}

function changeDivColor(key) {
   //var myKey=resultAsArray [0];

switch (key) {
    case 'b' :document.getElementById("66").style.background="#c98c8c";
    break;
    case 'a' : document.getElementById("65").style.background="#c98c8c";
    break;
    case 'c' :document.getElementById("67").style.background="#c98c8c";
    break;
    case 'd' : document.getElementById("68").style.background="#c98c8c";
    break;
    case 'e' :document.getElementById("69").style.background="#c98c8c";
    break;
    case 'f' : document.getElementById("67").style.background="#c98c8c";
    break;
    case 'g' :document.getElementById("71").style.background="#c98c8c";
    break;
    case 'h' : document.getElementById("72").style.background="#c98c8c";
    break;
    case 'i' : document.getElementById("73").style.background="#c98c8c";
    break;
    case 'j' :document.getElementById("74").style.background="#c98c8c";
    break;
    case 'k' : document.getElementById("75").style.background="#c98c8c";
    break;
    case 'l' :document.getElementById("76").style.background="#c98c8c";
    break;
    case 'm' : document.getElementById("77").style.background="#c98c8c";
    break;
    case 'n' :document.getElementById("78").style.background="#c98c8c";
    break;
    case 'o' : document.getElementById("79").style.background="#c98c8c";
    break;
    case 'p' : document.getElementById("80").style.background="#c98c8c";
    break;
    case 'q' :document.getElementById("81").style.background="#c98c8c";
    break;
    case 'r' : document.getElementById("82").style.background="#c98c8c";
    break;
    case 's' :document.getElementById("83").style.background="#c98c8c";
    break;
    case 't' : document.getElementById("84").style.background="#c98c8c";
    break;
    case 'u' : document.getElementById("85").style.background="#c98c8c";
    break;
    case 'v' :document.getElementById("86").style.background="#c98c8c";
    break;
    case 'w' : document.getElementById("87").style.background="#c98c8c";
    break;
    case 'x' :document.getElementById("88").style.background="#c98c8c";
    break;
    case 'y' : document.getElementById("89").style.background="#c98c8c";
    break;
    case 'z' : document.getElementById("90").style.background="#c98c8c";
   }
}
```

//This is my html - virtual keyboard

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="simrec.js"></script>

     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="simcss.css" />
</head>
<body>



<p id="q">say a word</p>




    <div id="container">
<textarea id="write" rows="6" cols="60"></textarea>
<ul id="keyboard">
<li class="symbol"><span class="off">`</span><span class="on">~</span></li>
<li class="symbol"><span class="off">1</span><span class="on">!</span></li>
<li class="symbol"><span class="off">2</span><span class="on">@</span></li>
<li class="symbol"><span class="off">3</span><span class="on">#</span></li>
<li class="symbol"><span class="off">4</span><span class="on">$</span></li>
<li class="symbol"><span class="off">5</span><span class="on">%</span></li>
<li class="symbol"><span class="off">6</span><span class="on">^</span></li>
<li class="symbol"><span class="off">7</span><span class="on">&amp;</span></li>
<li class="symbol"><span class="off">8</span><span class="on">*</span></li>
<li class="symbol"><span class="off">9</span><span class="on">(</span></li>
<li class="symbol"><span class="off">0</span><span class="on">)</span></li>
<li class="symbol"><span class="off">-</span><span class="on">_</span></li>
<li class="symbol"><span class="off">=</span><span class="on">+</span></li>
<li class="delete lastitem">delete</li>
<li class="tab">tab</li>
<li class="letter" style id="81">q</li>
<li class="letter" style id="87">w</li>
<li class="letter" style id="69">e</li>
<li class="letter" style id="82">r</li>
<li class="letter" style id="84">t</li>
<li class="letter" style id="89">y</li>
<li class="letter" style id="85">u</li>
<li class="letter" style id="73">i</li>
<li class="letter" style id="79">o</li>
<li class="letter" style id="81">p</li>
<li class="symbol"><span class="off">[</span><span class="on">{</span></li>
<li class="symbol"><span class="off">]</span><span class="on">}</span></li>
<li class="symbol lastitem"><span class="off">\</span><span class="on">|</span></li>
<li class="capslock">caps lock</li>
<li class="letter" style id="65">a</li>
<li class="letter" style id="83">s</li>
<li class="letter" style id="68">d</li>
<li class="letter" style id="70">f</li>
<li class="letter" style id="71">g</li>
<li class="letter" style id="72">h</li>
<li class="letter" style id="74">j</li>
<li class="letter" style id="75">k</li>
<li class="letter" style id="76">l</li>
<li class="symbol"><span class="off">;</span><span class="on">:</span></li>
<li class="symbol"><span class="off">'</span><span class="on">&quot;</span></li>
<li class="return lastitem">return</li>
<li class="left-shift">shift</li>
<li class="letter" style id="90">z</li>
<li class="letter" style id="88">x</li>
<li class="letter" style id="67">c</li>
<li class="letter" style id="86">v</li>
<li class="letter" style id="66">b</li>
<li class="letter" style id="78">n</li>
<li class="letter" style id="77">m</li>
<li class="symbol"><span class="off">,</span><span class="on">&lt;</span></li>
<li class="symbol"><span class="off">.</span><span class="on">&gt;</span></li>
<li class="symbol"><span class="off">/</span><span class="on">?</span></li>
<li class="right-shift lastitem">shift</li>
<li class="space lastitem">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
</div>




<script src = "simrec.js"></script>


<input type="button" value="Click to Speak" onclick="recognition.start()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what error are you facing? Or are you just asking to write code for you?

Comment: You are already listening to a `keydown` event. Just connect that with your function to adjust the color...

Comment: @KarelG fo you have a suggestion on how I could do that in the best way?

Comment: @BryndisThorsteinsdottir in the keydown event handler, add `changeDivColor(event.which);` after your `console.log`. That function is called each time you press a key. If you don't want this, add `if( allowCall )` before using that function. Then it's a case of simply setting `allowCall = true` or `allowCall = false` when you want to change color or not at each key presses.

Comment: Thanks @KarelG I will try that :) Another thing is that I need the resultArray to show one at a time, ie one key lights at a time. Right now the keys are lighting all at the same time.

   var i=0;
   while (i<resultAsArray.length) 
   changeDivColor(resultAsArray[i]); 

You wouldn't happen to know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @BryndisThorsteinsdottir There is no "next stepping" in your while loop. Try to perform the code steps manually. You will find out that `i` keeps being 0. Add `i++` at the end of the loop or use a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var chart = {
 't': 84,
 'a': 65,
 'b': 66,
 'l': 76,
 'e': 69
};
$(function() {
 $(window).on('keyup', function(e) {
  var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
  $('span').each(function() {
   var $t = $(this);
   var c = $t.text().trim().toLowerCase();
   if ( chart[c] == key ) {
    $t.addClass('light');
    setTimeout(function() {
     $t.removeClass('light');
    }, 1000);
   }
  });
 });
});
```

```css
span {
 color: #333;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 40px;
 font-weight: bold;
 transition: .2s ease;
}

.light {
 color: #ff9500;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>T</span>
<span>A</span>
<span>B</span>
<span>L</span>
<span>E</span>
```